# ASP Notification Mechanism

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, database, notifications

I am creating a website, where people can add each other as friend.

For example I got 2 users:

```
User ONE with UserID = 1
User TWO with UserID = 2
```

When `User One` adds `User Two`, I write this to a database, with an Integer to track the status:

`0 = waiting`
`1 = accepted (are now friends)`

If denied -> I just delete that record from the database.

When `User One` add `User Two`, I want to send a notification to `User Two`.

So `User Two` should get a notification about that `User One` has added him, without refreshing the page.

What can I use to create notifications after adding someone as friend?

Should I look to a kind of trigger on the database that sends something to the website after a record is added, or are there other mechanisms that you guys recommend me?

It's a ASPX website, without MVC.

The same mechanism I would like to use for a Message System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways of achieving this, from simplest to most complex:

1. Polling
   Write a javascript that calls a rest service on your site every x minutes and updates the DOM of the page
2. Long Polling
   Similar to polling but keeping an open connection to have instant replies without waiting between polls. Requires having an api that can keep a pool of open connection and a background thread on the server that polls the database for changes, which it percolates up to the javascript if needed
3. Web Sockets
   Upgrades the connection to a full two ways connection (websocket protocol). Similar to long polling server side.

As you can see any other option than 1. is fairly complex, but you can take a look at the [SingalR library](http://signalr.net/) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, what is the most recommended one?

Comment: large sites (facebook) implement all of them, degrading from 3 to 1. If you have only a few visitors go for 1. and move upwards if you have load issues.

Comment: But if I send a notification, and the user clicks on ''hide''-notification, the timer will recheck the database and send another notification, and this loop will continue, am I right? So the polling will 'spam' the user with notifications

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to poll the database for such updates, AJAX is mainly used to refrain from forms submissions by acting asynchronously.

Here is a simple [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) example of AJAX polling:

```
function doPoll(){
    $.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
        alert(data);  // process results here
        setTimeout(doPoll,5000);
    });
}
```

Also, as Brad M commented, you can "cache" the "Friends" table into the memory and poll against it rather than the DB - It would be much faster.

Comment: Or just poll the application cache (or cache server) for these types of events.

Comment: He didn't mentioned cache but it is indeed might be faster.